# Regular expression to match a string start with <i and not followed by 'mg' and end with '>'

Tags: java, regex

I have a requirement to check a string whether starting with `<i` and immediately not followed by `mg` and should end with `>`

I have tried the following regular expression but it did not work.

```
<[iI][^(mg|MG)][^>]*>
```

- `<i>`      :          Should match and return true
- `<ind value="abc">`      :           Should match and return true
- `<img/src=x onerror=alert("stack..!")>` :  Shouldn't match and return false

Please some help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use: `(?i)<i(?!mg)[^>]*>`

Comment: Does it have to be a regular expression?  It looks like you're trying to parse HTML, and regular expressions are notoriously bad at doing that.

Comment: It's better to give some reason when some one down vote question. I will learn something that not to repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with a negative lookahead:

```
(?i)<i(?!mg)[^>]*>
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sv3PHt/1/)

**RegEx Description:**

- `(?i)`: Modifier for ignore case
- `<i`: Match literal text `<i`
- `(?!mg)`: Negative lookahead to assert that we don't have `mg` at the next position
- `[^>]*`: Match 0 or more characters that are not `>`
- `>`: Match literal `>`

Comment: Clarify what didn't work. Did you check linked demo that shows all 3 examples in your question?

Comment: Hey Anuhava, Sorry yesterday I mistaken to test properly. Yes It's worked. Your help should be appreciate.